# REGEX (javascript) - Allow alphanumeric characters with special characters not in the first position

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to devise a regex expression that allows alphanumeric characters, as well as other characters as long as they're not in the first position.  Examples:

```
VALID: Test
VALID: Hello123
VALID: 456 Hi
VALID: 456-789
VALID: Hi-777
VALID: 333-Hi
VALID: Hello-There
VALID: What's Up
VALID: Hello#Goodbye

INVALID: -Hello
INVALID: &Goodbye
```

Here's my starting point, which only allows alphanumeric:

```
/[a-zA-Z]+/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `^[A-Za-z0-9]` to require an alphnum character in the first position (immediately following `^`, the start of the string), followed by whatever else you need.

```
# Specific set permitted -- add all the characters you need...
/^[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z-9, +-_&#'"]+$/

# Or anything permitted after the first position
# Use .* instead of .+ if a single character string is permissible.
/^[A-Za-z0-9].+$/
```

Comment: don't you need a `+` after the first range and a asterix on the second? `/^[A-Za-z0-9]+[A-Za-z-9,+-_&#'"]*$/`

Comment: @TI No you should not have it there - omitting `+` after the first character class means you only need _one_ (no more, no less) alpha-num character at the start of the string. But then the second character class permits additional alpha-num chars, as well as other chars.  The second could be a `+` or `*`, depending on whether more characters are required or not.  Using `*` would permit strings of only one character (the first one)

Comment: thanks I read it better now, but i think there needs to be a space or smt in the second range `^[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9,+-_&#'" ]+$`

Comment: @TI I added the space - the OP needs to put in all the permitted chars there, or use the second option with `.+`

Comment: How come you are (implicitly) asserting at least 2 character? The `+` should be `*`, IMO

Comment: @nhahtdh The OP has not specified one way or the other on length requirements.

Comment: @Michael: Is there any particular reason that you prefer `+` over `*`? I'd choose to be more liberal and go for `*` in this case.

Comment: @nhahtdh Just a matter of whether more chars are required (+), or if a 1-char string is permissible (*).  Up to the OP's needs.

Comment: @nhahtdh I already did, in the comments above the second regex.

Answer (score 3):

Try this regular expression :

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9].*$/
```

Answer (score 0):

`/^\w/` if you only need to test, `/^\w.*$/`, if you need the entire string to be matched as well.
If you allow the empty string as well, you can use `/^(\w|$)/`, read as the string begins with a word character or with its end (is empty), or `/^(\w.*)?$/`, read as the string is a word character followed by anything, once or not at all.