# How to fail validation if the user attempts to submit HTML?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, validation

I have a `RequiredFieldValidator` that works, except for when I try to submit a string that contains the following characters:

```
&#
```

Our web server rejects the request, stating that we're not allowed to submit HTML.

How can I perform client side validation to prevent a string containing those characters, or other characters which can be interpreted as HTML?

Comment: what about replacing the characters?

Comment: Shouldn't you encode the html at Client Side then decode at Server Side (web server) why restricting User?

Comment: Does server reject specific character set or all non-alpha-numeric chars. In that case you just use regex in javascript and test input against `[a-zA-Z0-9]*`

Answer (score 0):

I had such an issue with "<" ">" tags.
I add an event handler to my form. And when I hit submit button javasript code works before the values are sent to the server.

```
<from ..... onsubmit = "return confSubmit();">
```

and add a function to my javascript which changes that characters:

```
  function confSubmit() {
     document.getElementById("Employee").value = document.getElementById("Employee").value.replace(/</g, "&lt;");
document.getElementById("Employee").value = document.getElementById("Employee").value.replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
    }
```

Comment: I think you first need to replace `&` with `&amp;` - for the case when the original text already contains a "&lt;" that you do not want to decode server side.

Comment: Yes, of course, I don't bring the whole code, just to show my solution :)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to restrict user to input certain characters only or disallow to key in certain characters. As an example you can enable or disable certain keys to be allowed in a text control like

```
// check for only upper, lower char with [space]
function onlyAlpha(e, t) {
   if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
      var n = event.keyCode;
      if (n > 64 && n < 91 || n > 96 && n < 123 || n == 32) {
         return true
      } else {}
   } else {
      var n = t.charCode;
      if (n > 64 && n < 91 || n > 96 && n < 123 || n == 32 || n == 0) {
         return true
      } else {}
   }
   return false
}
```

Allow only alpha-numerics

```
// check for upper, lower, [space], [,], [.] and numerals
function onlyAlphaNumeric(e, t) {
   if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
      var n = event.keyCode;
      if (n > 64 && n < 91 || n > 96 && n < 123 || n == 32 || n == 46 || n == 39 || n >= 48 && n <= 57) {
         return true
      } else {}
   } else {
      var n = t.charCode;
      if (n > 64 && n < 91 || n > 96 && n < 123 || n == 0 || n == 32 || n == 46 || n == 39 || n >= 48 && n <= 57) {
         return true
      } else {}
   }
   return false
}
```

You can use them as

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtText1" runat="server" onkeypress="return onlyAlpha(this,event);" MaxLength="30" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtText2" runat="server" onkeypress="return onlyAlphaNumeric(this,event);" MaxLength="30" />
```

Using such functions you can allow / disallow users to fill in certain characters. One concern you need to handle here is to capture <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>. You can find many SO posts to handle this.

If you are convenient using **regexes** you can take cues from these SO posts [javascript only allow alphanumeric and hyphen - value in text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8661254/javascript-only-allow-alphanumeric-and-hyphen-value-in-text-field?rq=1) and [REGEX (javascript) - Allow alphanumeric characters with special characters not in the first position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976901/regex-javascript-allow-alphanumeric-characters-with-special-characters-not-i?rq=1)

To prevent the form from submitting, a more better approach would be to use some client side JavaScript library / jQuery plugin. There are plenty of them available.

To play safe it would be much better to apply server side validation on the inputs using regexes or custom check such as

```
If txtText1.Text.Contains("#") OrElse txtText2.Contains("<") Then
    'take action
End If
```